# Comparing new & repeat caller's phone numbers, via Google Apps Script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a list of 73k caller's phone numbers, over 5 years. I need an accumulative chronological list of each unique number so that I can compare the ratio of new to repeat callers.

I use the following code to extract only phone calls during business hours and build the full list of numbers - I can't get Google App Script to build the unique list so I use the =unique formula in Google Sheet to get my unique list of callers -

```
    var ss19 = SpreadsheetApp.openById('1zkrkc2ZqT4KLDK5_-DDuyBsXj-t0p_kYyJbLArDWFfc')
    var cl19 = ss19.getSheetByName('2019 Log')
    var log19 = cl19.getRange(2, 1, cl19.getLastRow(), 5).getValues();
    var unique = resultSheet.getSheetByName('Unique');
    var callers = resultSheet.getSheetByName('Callers');
    var callerList = callers.getRange(1,2,callers.getLastRow(), 1).getValues();
        for( var i = 1; i<log19.length; i++){
            if(log19[i][4] > 0){
              if(log19[i][2].indexOf("Voicemail") == -1){
                if(log19[i][0].indexOf("(") == 0){
                longList.push([log19[i][0]])
                }
          }
            }
          }
          callers.getRange(1,2,longList.length,longList[0].length).setValues(longList)
        }

function getRatio() {
  var newCallers=[];
  var repeated=[];
  for(var i=0;i<callerList.length;i++) {//if there is a one line header start at var i=1
    if(newCallers.indexOf(callerList[i][1])==-1) {
      newCallers.push([callerList[i][1],callerList[i][0]]);//new callers array date and number
    }else{
      repeated.push([callerList[i][1]]);//repeated callers array date and number
    }
  }
//  return newCallers.length/repeated.length;
  Logger.log(newCallers.length)
```

Comment: OK. What is your question?

Comment: That's the part I am struggling with. Anything I have coded to this point, exceeds the execution time limit Google allows for.

Comment: It will help to share what you have done to solve the problem. You cant expect others to give you a completely baked solution.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverFlow. Please take this chance to read [ask] and [mcve]. This information will help you to get a better response to your questions. You also might find it useful take our [tour].

Comment: Agreed - however, I am very new to GAS and I fear I am to far down the wrong hole to correct the problem - I will give you what I have tried, but I'm looking for advice outside of the box

Answer (score 0):

## Ratio of New to Repeat Callers

Assuming that dates are in column1 and phone numbers are in column2.  This will also export the first time callers and the repeat callers into two other sheets (date and number). You can save time by sorting them in the spreadsheet and then running the code without the sort.

```
function getRatioOfNewToRepeatCallers() {
  var ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var sh=ss.getSheetByName('Callers');
  var rg=sh.getRange(2,1,sh.getLastRow()-1,sh.getLastColumn());//Assuming a one row header
  var vA=rg.getValues();
  var newCallers=[];
  var newDC=[];
  var repeated=[];
  rg.sort({column:1,ascending:true});
  for(var i=0;i<vA.length;i++) {
    if(newCallers.indexOf(vA[i][1])==-1) {
      newCallers.push(vA[i][1]);//new callers array date and number
      newDC.push([vA[i][0],vA[i][1]]);
    }else{
      repeated.push([vA[i][0],vA[i][1]]);//repeated callers array date and number
    }
  }
  exportToSheet({dataA:newDC,sheetname:'New Callers'});
  exportToSheet({dataA:repeated,sheetname:'Repeated Callers'});
  Logger.log(newCallers.length/repeated.length);
  return newCallers.length/repeated.length;
}

function sheetExists(sheetname) {
  var ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var allshts=ss.getSheets();
  var exists=false;
  for(var i=0;i<allshts.length;i++) {
    if(allshts[i].getName()==sheetname) {
      exists=true;
      break;
    }
  }
  return exists;
}

function exportToSheet(exportObj) {
  var ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var sh;
  if(!sheetExists(exportObj.sheetname)){
    var sh=ss.insertSheet(exportObj.sheetname);
  }else{
    var sh=ss.getSheetByName(exportObj.sheetname);
  }
  sh.clear();
  sh.appendRow(['Date','Number']);
  sh.getRange(2,1,exportObj.dataA.length,2).setValues(exportObj.dataA);
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for  your time - I have done something to your code as of now, the if fails nothing, everything ends up in the newCaller Array

Comment: Okay it's working now with a one row header.  Originally, I was using the array.indexOf() but I had a 2d array so that wasn't working.